# How to get custom attribute value in angular 13

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular13

I have a dropdown like this and I need to get the value on button click. but it always returns null. Need to get the cus_id value, without jquery

html file

```
<select #myselect>
    <option *ngFor="let title of titleArray" [attr.data-id]="title.cus_id" [value]="title.Value">
      {{title.Text}}
    </option>
</select>

 <button (click)="save(myselect)">Save data</button>
```

ts file

```
save(e:any){
  let cus_id=e.getAttribute('data-id');
  alert(cus_id)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We could create a two way binding and save the "selected" value option to a variable. Because this is a regular html select we use `[(ngModel)]` for two way binding.

Also, we also normally use camelCase for property names when using javascript `title.Text` -> `title.text`, `myselect` -> `mySelect`, `title.Value` -> `title.value` etc.

We can then access the variable `selected` for processing on `(click)` event which triggers function `onSave()` click  in typescript part of the code.

I use `?` when accessing property to conditionally check the prop exists first, this is just in case.

I use `parseInt()` to turn `cus_id` coming from template as string, back to a number.

If you don't plan on overwriting the variable prefer `const` over `let`.

Avoid `any` type `e:any` -> `e: Event` if possible (though not needed in my example).

If possible always prefer strong typing with `interface` or `class`, it will help you in the long run, that's the beauty of typescript - we strong type stuff.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  selected: string;

  titleArray: Title[] = [
    { cus_id: 1, text: 'Hancook', value: '123' },
    { cus_id: 2, text: 'I am legend', value: '456' },
    { cus_id: 3, text: 'Amber the turd', value: '789' },
  ];

  onSave() {
    console.log('now saving: ', this.selected);
    const arrayItem = this.titleArray.find((item) => item.cus_id === parseInt(this.selected));
    window.alert(JSON.stringify(arrayItem));
  }
}

export interface Title {
  cus_id: number;
  text: string;
  value: string;
}
```

Html

```html
<select #myselect [(ngModel)]="selected">
  <option *ngFor="let title of titleArray" [value]="title?.cus_id">
    {{ title?.text }}
  </option>
</select>

<br />
<br />

<button (click)="onSave()">Save data</button>
```

This could be further simplified instead of using `[value]="title?.cus_id"` we could do `[value]="title"` and pass the obj `title` to variable `selected`, then we wouldn't have to search it from `titleArray[]` nor interpolate strings to number using `parseInt()` - but that's up to you.

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-select-option-dropdown-qt4yvp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Findex.html

Welcome to SO, nicely formatted question.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, we have two proper ways of managing forms, building reactive forms, and template-driven forms. I recommend you to check them out in [Introduction to forms in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview).

That said, I presume going for template-driven form is best for your particular use-case, and you ultimately want to get the `cus_id` property of the selected `title`.

#### Step 1: Import `FormsModule`

In your app/root module (or module where your component is declared), import `FormsModule`.

```ts
import { FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    FormsModule, //  import here
    ...
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { ... }
```

#### Step 2: Declare a data model for holding the current selection

```ts
export class MyComponent {
  // list of selectable options
  titleArray = [ ... ];

  selectedTitle?: MyComponent['titleArray']; //  this property will serve as the data model for the selection input
}
```

#### Step 3: Bind data model to view

Connect the data model to the view such that whenever the user selects a different option, the value of the data model will automatically update.

```html
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedTitle">
    <option *ngFor="let title of titleArray" [ngValue]="title">
      {{title.Text}}
    </option>
</select>

<button (click)="onSave(selectedTitle)">Save data</button>
```

#### Step 4: Process the selected option

Once the user hits save, you will now be able to process the actual object corresponding to the option that the user has currently selected.

```ts
// in the controller

onSave(title = this.selectedTitle) {
  console.log(title.cus_id);
}
```